# How to get explicit child types as Property

Tags: c#, properties

Let's say I have a Class:

```
class AbstractPerson{

AbstractAttribute attr {get; set;}

}
```

Now, in the child Class of AbstractPerson, I want to use the attr but, in the special case like so:

```
class Pilot: AbstractPerson {

...
(attr as SpecialAttribute).pilotID;
...
}
```

Because I don't want to do this, everytime I call `attr`, I want to have a property in `Pilot` that gives back a typecasted version of `attr`, but I'm not getting this to work.

So, this doesn't work:

```
class Pilot: AbstractPerson {   
AbstractAttribute attr {
get
{
return (attr as SpecialAttribute);
}
set;
}

}
```

Is this even possible?

*** I know that by convention, "attr" should be in PascalCase, I just forgot for this example. In reality the Person is a Controller and the attr a View.

Comment: Well, you return `attr` as `SpecialAttribute`, but since the property is still of type `AbstractAttribute`, you're right back at where you started from. You could have a *different* property like `SpecialAttribute attrSpecial { get { return attr as SpecialAttribute; } }` and then only use that inside `Pilot`.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I though about having another property, but then I wouldn't have the ONE property that suffices two things: act as the special thing it is but still provide all the abstract thing it certainly has. I think the generics solution is best. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that:

```
class SpecialAttribute : AbstractAttribute {}
```

You can use generics:

```
class AbstractPerson<T>
    where T : AbstractAttribute
{
    T attr {get; set;}
}

class Pilot: AbstractPerson<SpecialAttribute> 
{ 
    /* ... */ 
    void Foo()
    {
        // attr is a SpecialAttribute here
        attr.PropertyOfSpecialAttribute = "bar";
    }
}
```

Note, that you're misusing `as` operator.
If there is a possibility, that `attr` isn't a `SpecialAttribute`, than `as` *must* be followed by null-checking:

```
var foo = bar as Foo;
if (foo != null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Otherwise (if `attr` *must* be `SpecialAttribute`), you *must* use type casting:

```
var foo = (Foo)bar;
```

to throw `InvalidCastException`, if the type is not expected.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation, I prefer Dennis's suggestion. That said, you may not be able to change the base class to use it. If that's the case, then you can do something not quite as good but still useful:

```
class AbstractPerson
{
    AbstractAttribute Attribute { get; set; }
}

class Pilot : AbstractPerson
{
    PilotAttribute PilotAttribute
    {
        get { return (PilotAttribute)AbstractAttribute; }
        set { AbstractAttribute = value; }
    }
}
```

Naturally, this approach requires that `PilotAttribute` actually derive from `AbstractAttribute`, something that is not actually required in the generic solution (unless you specifically want it to be). It also does not provide the level of security that the generic solution does: the `AbstractAttribute` is still present and could be assigned a value not of the `PilotAttribute` type. So you do have to be careful to not do that (preferably by avoiding using the base attribute when dealing with instances of `Pilot`).

It is also possible to simply hide the base `AbstractAttribute` property with a new one. But I detest member hiding and IMHO all that would do here is make the code more confusing.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Thank you for this alternative! I'll consider it, when it is more practical!